# laravel last() function like sql

Tags: laravel

Is there  a function last() in laravel like sql? I dont want to use `orderby('price','desc')->first()`

here is my current query

```
$this->businessfund->whereBusiness_id($id)->whereCategory('Investment')
        ->select(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date, count(*) as total_trade, last(price), min(price) as min, max(price) as max, sum(shares) as volume, sum(total_price) as total_price'))
        ->groupBy('date')
        ->get();
```

How can I get the first and last data inserted by dates?

Comment: you can use `first()` and `latest()` methods

Comment: Using first and lastest will return 1 data. I need to get the first and last data inserted by dates.

Comment: `->latest()` and `->oldest()` are shortcuts for `->orderBy()`, check here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1306

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot do a union of two `order by`'s `limit 1` in sql.